# Header Block not displaying in magento 2

Tags: magento2

https://www.nishatre.com/ is the live url for my website. ALl of a sudden my header block has disappeared.. Can anyone kindly help how to bring back the header block?

my header code -

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * @var \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header $block
 */

$welcomeMessage = $block->getWelcome();

$_config = $this->helper('Sm\Shiny\Helper\Data');
$headerStyle = $_config->getThemeLayout('header_style');
$compile_less = $_config->getAdvanced('compile_less');
$login_customer =  $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Customer');

if($login_customer->customerLoggedIn()){
    $loggedin = 'loggedin';
} else{
    $loggedin = '';
}

include (dirname(__FILE__).'/header-style/'.$headerStyle.'.phtml');
if( $compile_less ){
    include (dirname(__FILE__).'/compile_less.phtml');
}
?>

<?php 
    if($_config->getAdvanced('show_newsletter_popup')){
        echo $block->getChildHtml('form.subscribe.popup'); 
    }
?>

<?php if($_config->getGeneral('menu_ontop') == 1){ ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        require([
            'jquery'
        ], function ($) {
            $window = $(window);
            if($('.header-bottom').length){
                menu_offset_top = $('.header-bottom').offset().top;
                function processScroll() {
                    var scrollTop = $window.scrollTop();
                    if ( scrollTop >= menu_offset_top) {
                        $('.header-bottom').addClass('menu-on-top');
                        $('body').addClass('body-on-top');
                    } else if (scrollTop <= menu_offset_top) {
                        $('.header-bottom').removeClass('menu-on-top');
                        $('body').removeClass('body-on-top');
                    }
                }
                processScroll();
                $window.scroll(function(){
                    processScroll();
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: try to remove cache:storage and check in log files

Comment: tried.. but not a cache problem.

Comment: What is the last thing that you did on your site?

Comment: You should explain more if any change was made, and module installed, or any services you are using. Any mode change of Magento2 on the server.

Comment: Anything in log files? Any last change you remember ? @supriya

Comment: Update your question with header code.

Comment: last thing i did was i updated the complete app folder from my local file.

Comment: i didnot do any change in log file.

Comment: my header code -

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using a custom Magento2 theme. 
I believe your Magento cant read the below file.
Try changing to correct ownership or remove pub/static folders and create the files again.

```
include (dirname(__FILE__).'/header-style/'.$headerStyle.'.phtml');
```